# Error: Can´t access facebook comment plugin admin page

Tags: plugins, comments, admin, facebook, curl

The plugin i'm talking about is [facebook-comments-plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/)

The problem is i can´t access admin page: /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=fbcomments

**This error is happening:**

> PHP Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: URL file-access
>   is disabled in the server configuration in
>   E:\home\intothebac\Web\wp-content\plugins\facebook-comments-plugin\class-admin.php
>   on line 194 PHP Warning:
>   DOMDocument::load(http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)
>   [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could
>   be found in
>   E:\home\intothebac\Web\wp-content\plugins\facebook-comments-plugin\class-admin.php
>   on line 194 PHP Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml" in
>   E:\home\intothebac\Web\wp-content\plugins\facebook-comments-plugin\class-admin.php
>   on line 194

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the plugin file to make it work. I think it can help someone and even the plugin's author should consider making these changes.

on class-admin.php, create this function at the beggining (can be line 9):

```
function loadXmlByCurl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    return $xml;
}
```

Now replace this line

```
$dom_object->load("http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml");
```

by

```
$xml = loadXmlByCurl("http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml");
$dom_object = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
```

and you are ready to go.